# Issue with adding content to a content type

Tags: nodes

I am developing a Drupal 7 website. My site is in its final stage. All of sudden according to the clients requirement I need to add a new content type to the site. The content type is added successfully, now when I am trying to add content to the newly added content type it's not showing in **Add Content**.
I don't even have the clue when this issue initiated. Please help.

Comment: Try clearing cache ? Did you check permissions ? Are you trying to add as super admin ?

Comment: Had cleared cache n number of times. Permissions are all right. I am not creating any super admin, just added a new content type. And unable to add content to it.

Comment: Try rebuilding permissions in status report page ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Anil. I have check the status report page, There are few update missing. No other issues reported.

Comment: No matter issues reported, rebuild permissions and clear menu cache (in that order)

Comment: possible duplicate of [New content type not showing up in Add Content](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100323/new-content-type-not-showing-up-in-add-content)

Answer (score 0):

That page is tied to the menu system.

It loads the node/add menu item, then makes the content type links from the children of that menu item.

Go to the navigation menu (admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation) and make sure that content type is in the list under the add content menu item.

Comment: Rooby, thanks for the answer man. I have tried that too. But in the navigation menu The newly added content type is not listed. I tried adding manually. But that didn't worked.... :(